# Why does my observable doesn't catch error and stops working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-observable

I have a form. The user enters inputs and then a http request is sent to the backend to get data.

In the HTML template I have

```
data$ | async
```

In the component code I first have:

```
  data$: Observable<DataResponse> = this.userInput$.asObservable()
      .pipe(
          tap(() => this.loadingService.show()),
          switchMap(userInput => this.dataService.getData(
              userInput.textInput,
              userInput.numberInput).pipe(
                  finalize(() => this.loadingService.hide())
              )
          )
      );
```

It worked fine when there is no error. But when this.dataService.getData(...) returns an error (HttpErrorResponse); the observable stops sending request now.

I've tried to add catchError in many places but doesn't seem to work. It seems the catchError doesn't catch anything even when there is an error. Any advice would be appreciate tanks.

```
  data$: Observable<DataResponse> = this.userInput$.asObservable()
      .pipe(
          tap(() => this.loadingService.show()),
          switchMap(userInput => this.dataService.getData(
              userInput.textInput,
              userInput.numberInput).pipe(
              catchError(error => {
                console.error('Error occurred:', error);
                return of(null);
              }),
                  finalize(() => this.loadingService.hide())
              )
          )
      );
```

Comment: This code seems _so_ unnecessarily complex for "submit a form and get a response". Why the `.asObservable()`, .`tap()`, `.switchMap()` and `.pipe(catchError())`? Why not just use two-way data binding in the template and have a HttpService make a get and return that? It looks like you're sending requests when the user types input? Please provide more detail.

Comment: If you were to create a minimal repro on stackblitz, it'd be easier to help you out. If you want to push that burden to people reviewing your question, you'll get less answers

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine and the idea to catch the error  directly in switchMap is correct, but this only works if `this.dataService.getData()` throws an error with `throwError` for example:  `return throwError(() => new Error("oh nooo"));`
but it's won't work if it throws an error like this:  `throw new Error('oh noooo');`.

so what you have to do is to wrap your `this.dataService.getData()` in a try/catch block. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Throw an error manually in your service because `catchError` will trigger when seeing an error in the observable stream.

For example:

```
 of('day', 'midday', 'night')
    .pipe(
      map(timeOfDay => {
        if (timeOfDay === 'midday') {
          throw 'too early!';
        }
        return timeOfDay;
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err) // 'too early!'
      })
    )
```